# What does "randomically" mean?

Tags: meaning, orthography, is-it-a-word, programming, errors

I've just read the O'Reilly book *[Getting Started with Storm](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024835.do)* and encoutered the word *randomically*. I highly suspect this is a made up word, but a quick google found it in use [here](http://www.dbatodba.com/sql-server/how-tos/how-to-retrieve-rows-randomically-in-sql-server/), [here](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2011-August/msg00113.html), and [here](http://www.office-archive.com/1-outlook/a229af171dd75925.htm). Is this some obscure technical term perhaps? Or is it a case of a covergent devolution of English?

I don’t think this is a misspelling, as they (authors of the book) use the word *randomly* in a previous sentence (emphasis mine):

> Shuffle Grouping is the most commonly used grouping. It takes a single parameter (the
> source component) and sends each tuple emitted by the source to a *randomly* chosen
> bolt warranting that each consumer will receive the same number of tuples.
>
> The shuffle grouping is useful for doing atomic operations such as a math operation.
> However, if the operation can’t be *randomically* distributed, such as the example in
> Chapter 2 where you needed to count words, you should consider the use of other
> grouping.

Did they intend it to mean something else? If so, what is that other meaning?

Comment: Why do I have a downvote? Could the downvoted/someone more observant see what I've done wrong?

Comment: "Randomically" is not found anywhere in the Google Books corpus (see: [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=randomically&year_start=1500&year_end=2009&corpus=0&smoothing=0)). Nor is it in any dictionary (see: [OneLook](http://onelook.com/?w=randomically&ls=a)). This is a general reference question and as such I am voting to close.

Comment: @ΜετάEd because it can't be found in general sources (some of which I checked), it's general reference? Since when was lack of evidence proof?

Comment: Unfortunately, all you have proved by your edit is that the word is not systematically misspelled throughout the book. Sometimes a copyeditor lets one get by them.

Comment: A bona fide technical term would have shown up in at least one technical work in the Google Books corpus. That's not absence of evidence: that's evidence of absence. There's an interesting statistical concept that applies here called "prior probability": counterintuitive but very useful.

Comment: @ΜετάEd still I don't think I would have concluded that from simply looking at the sources you provided (intrestingly, none of the answers have used either). I *don't* think this is general reference though.

Comment: Your excerpt reads "randomically distributed, *such as the example in Chapter 2*". If you refer to Chapter 2 for the example, you will find it described "in *randomly* distributed fashion". It's not clear to me why your question does not mention this or take it into account.

Comment: @ΜετάEd I didn't notice that to start with.

Comment: @Pureferret Actually, a google search of this word only gives me programming web links where this word is commonly used. Maybe you should ask this on a different SE to find out how randomically is used and why it is used instead of random or randomly?

Comment: Randomically obviously means comically random. As in: "It's funny how I keep running into you" -> "I just keep randomically meeting you!" Source: Page 59 of the Official Newspeak dictionnary, 2010 Edition.

Comment: @ΜετάEd and everyone else jumping on the General Reference bandwagon: since when is a fairly complex corpus search a "single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information"? You did some research and came to a conclusion based on it; congratulations, now ***go post it as an answer already!***

Comment: @Marthaª (i) I did post an answer. (ii) Searching dictionaries with OneLook is a complex corpus search?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Where the authors of the book wrote *randomically*, they meant *randomly* and in fact intended to write *randomly*. This is demonstrably true.

1. *Randomically* is not a word known to specialists and having a technical meaning (even an obscure one), because nobody is using it in published works – it is not found anywhere in the Google Books corpus (see: *[Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=randomically&year_start=1500&year_end=2009&corpus=0&smoothing=0))*, nor has any lexicographer discovered the word and included it in a dictionary (see: *[OneLook](http://onelook.com/?w=randomically&ls=a)*).
2. It is not a term coined by the authors of the book, or they would have defined it.
3. The one place where it is used in the book (in Chapter 3 – see the excerpt in the question) refers to an example in Chapter 2, but there the example is described “in *randomly* distributed fashion”.
4. Jonathan Leibiusky (co-author) and one of the editors at O’Reilly have just sent me a nice thank-you note for [reporting the error](http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920024835).

Comment: +1 for Word of God from me, too, but don't you think that's further evidence that this question is in no way, shape, or form "general reference"?

Comment: @Marthaª No, just a form of absolute confirmation that addresses the OP's lingering doubts. I feel the lack of any entries in dictionaries searched by OneLook (my point 1) was more than enough; the OP seemed to need several more nails driven in before acknowledging the existence of a coffin. :-)

Comment: #4 on its own is a sufficient reason, unless we had reason to doubt the statement by those involved in the production of the book. :-)  That said, #1-3 are great examples of how we would deduce the answer on our own had an authoritative source not been available to answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the 66 results on *[Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=randomically&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)*, this is simply a misspelling made by – and this is an educated guess – non-native speakers of English. The candidates on the first couple of pages of the ~15000 results that *randomically* returns on *Google* are also of a similar nature. The authors of the book that you're reading fall into the same category.

So, no, it’s not an obscure technical term. It’s also not devolution of English. It’s just a relatively obscure misspelling.

Comment: I don't think it's a mispelling, see my edit.

Comment: I reckon it's a glowing indictment of O'Reilly's editing.

Comment: @Pureferret Well noted. But that could simply be an editor missing a spot :) If you look at the Books results, you'll find that there are many instances where the authors have used "_randomically chosen_" unlike in your provided example.

Comment: What I don't get is why ["randomically"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22randomically%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22randomically%22&hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&ei=h5_kUKboM8ed0QWSwoDQCw&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1339&bih=835) in ***quotes*** starts by saying "about 65 results", and peters out at 28 entries. But your version *without quotes* starts with "about 80 results", and peters out at 44 entries. Weird.

Answer (score 5):

I have never heard this word before. I suspect it is simply an error, and that the writers meant *randomly*. I couldn’t find anything that defined it, and in the examples you gave, they appeared to mean *randomly*.

If someone else on here is aware of a technical definition for this word, I’ll gladly yield.

Comment: See my edit, I don't think they mean randomly.

Comment: If they had meant something other than randomly, they probably would have defined it in the book, since it is not a commonly used technical term. I think it's an error.

Answer (score 3):

By the phrase “the operation can’t be randomically distributed”, the authors of *Getting Started with Storm* are saying that a procedure based on randomness is unsuitable. In the first paragraph you quoted they point out that Shuffle Grouping uses randomness to allocate jobs; in the second, they say that jobs for an earlier example, word counting, cannot be distributed on a random basis.

The authors may have a valid basis for the distinction they attempt to make, but *randomically* is something of a clumsy nonce word rather than a distinguished addition to the language. As for your links to previous occurrences of the word, all three of them appear to have been written by persons not highly skilled in English:

- In the [first](http://www.dbatodba.com/sql-server/how-tos/how-to-retrieve-rows-randomically-in-sql-server/) link, “First, let's create a table to performance some tests” and “This code didn't work with me” are telling signs.
- In the [second](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2011-August/msg00113.html) link, “If I start it manually, it boot fine … it only show the log of the guests that boot” is indicative.
- In the [third](http://www.office-archive.com/1-outlook/a229af171dd75925.htm) link, “This happen to some EMAILs but not to others … Proceeding again in the same way I, finally, send the email”.

That is, those links don’t support *randomically* as a valid and useful construction.

Comment: That's a good point. If an article has many spelling and grammar errors, that's pretty good grounds to suspect that an unfamiliar word is, in fact, a mistake of some kind. If an article was otherwise impeccable in its language, I'd take an unfamiliar word more seriously.